# Register multiple instances of IHostedService with different constructor parameters (DI and non-DI) in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.0

I have an environment with 4 identical devices that I have to connect to and request some parameters via TCP connection (each device with its IP address).
I've implemented a class for a single device that needs some parameters (like IP address, port, polling intervals etc...)

The class implements `BackgroundService` interface and has a constructor like this one below:

```
public RemoteDevice(RemoteDeviceConfig config, ILogger<RemoteDevice> logger)
```

Inside the class there is an implementation of the `ExecuteAsync` method with a `while{}` loop inside, that does all the logic.

I want to build a Worker Service that handles multiple instances of that class, based on a configuration file (eg. config file with an array of devices)

In Program.cs I would do:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseSystemd()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<RemoteDevice>(); //First device
            services.AddHostedService<RemoteDevice>(); //Second device
            ...
            services.AddHostedService<RemoteDevice>(); //n-th device

        });
...
//Methods to load configuration 
...
```

Without the `RemoteDeviceConfig` constructor parameter, the `ILogger` gets injected , but if I add it, I don't know how to inject my `RemoteDeviceConfig`class

What am I getting wrong?

I'm using .NET Core 3.0 with VS2019 and Worker Service Template project.

**UPDATE - ACCEPTED ANSWER**

I've accepted *@gldraphael* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58625022/11340762) , and I would add some details about the logging part specified in the answer's comments.

Problem: use ILogger implementation in classes instantiated in main Worker class.

Solution: inject ILoggerFactory in Worker class and use it to create loggers for subclasses

*`DeviceMainClass`* and *`DeviceConfig`* are respectively a generic device manager and its configuration.

*Worker.cs*

```
List<DeviceMainClass> devices;
//Pass ILoggerFactory to worker constructor for Dependency Injection
//On worker start, instantiate all subclasses and create logger for each class
public Worker(IOptions<List<DeviceConfig>> options, ILogger<Worker> logger, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    devices = new List<DeviceMainClass>();
    foreach(var device in _config)
    {
        devices.Add(new DeviceMainClass(_loggerFactory.CreateLogger<DeviceMainClass>(),...other parameters));
    }

    _logger = logger;
    _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    _config = options.Value;
}

...

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {


        //***for testing purposes only, repeats every second***
        _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

*DeviceMainClass*

```
private readonly ILogger<DeviceMainClass> _logger;

//Use
public DeviceMainClass(ILogger<DeviceMainClass> logger, ...other parameters)
{
    _logger = logger;
    ...
}
```

Comment: could you explain: "Without the RemoteDeviceConfig constructor parameter, the ILogger gets injected , but if I add it, I don't know how to inject my RemoteDeviceConfigclass"? How are you adding "it"?

Comment: A hosted service is a *service*, not a device or a singleton object. You need to create one hosted service, eg `DeviceMonitor` that will configure and monitor multiple devices itself

Comment: @gldraphael I tried to remove the "RemoteDeviceConfig" parameter from the class constructor, so the AddHostedService method succesfully start the service (only the first perhaps)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok , so you're suggesting to instantiate the Device class multiple times in this DeviceMonitor class? How to get to the ILogger then?

Comment: Where does `RemoteDeviceConfig` come from? DI can't work with *multiple* instances of the same object, not unless you can specify a name for it.

Comment: @Simon the same way you already get it. In the service's constructor, and then pass it to the classes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `RemoteDeviceConfig` is a configuration class that contains public properties like IPAddress string , port and so on..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wanna do something like this:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Devices": [
    { "Name": "D1" },
    { "Name": "D2" },
    { "Name": "D3" },
    { "Name": "D4" }
  ]
}
```

`CreateHostBuilder()`:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.Configure<List<DeviceConfig>>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Devices"));
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
```

**Worker:**

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
        private readonly List<DeviceConfig> config;

        public Worker(IOptions<List<DeviceConfig>> options, ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            config = options.Value;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {

                foreach(var device in config)
                {
                    // TODO: Process each device here
                    _logger.LogInformation("Processing device {name}", device.Name);
                }


                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

If your current `RemoteDevice` class has state information, create a `List<RemoteDevice>` in the worker and initialize from configuration.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I have only a question: can I pass the `ILogger<Worker> _logger` to each device class? I want to be able to log information from within the devices class.

Comment: @Simon yes you can. You may want to inject `ILoggerFactory` into the worker, and create a new logger per device class.

Comment: can you show me an example? I can't find anything helpful even on MSDN .. thank you!

Comment: Here's the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0. Add ILoggerFactory to worker's constructor, and use it to create `ILogger<RemoteDevice>` instances.

Comment: you mean like this? `public Worker(IOptions<List<DeviceConfig>> options, ILogger<Worker> logger, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
            _config = options.Value;
        }`
and then
`foreach(var device in _config)
                {
                    devices.Add(new RemoteDevice(_loggerFactory.CreateLogger<RemoteDevice>(),device.Name));
                }`

EDIT: it's not so readable in the comments.. how to post a more clean reply?

Comment: I've updated the main question to add some details about the answer.

Comment: @Simon you might want to initialise the list in the constructor. Right now it's happening on every iteration of the main loop.

Comment: I know. It's just for testing purposes. I'll update the post to be more clear

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party, but I'll add my 2 cents. The above answers don't take full advantage of the DI framework, and instead create a dummy worker that acts like as a secondary nested DI container, which in my opinion defeats the purpose of DI.
What you want to do is utilize **named** options, and implementation factories.

For configuration, structure your json like this:

```
"Devices":
{
  "Config1": {...},
  "Config2": {...},
  ...
}
```

When configuring get the Devices section, enumerate the children, and add each config with a name. For simplicity we will use the full path of the individual configuration:

```
IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> configSection = context.Configuration.GetSection("Devices").GetChildren();
foreach (IConfigurationSection section in configSection)
{
  services.Configure<RemoteDeviceConfig>(section.Path, section);
  //continued below...
}
```

Now you have all your configs, but your RemoteDevice class needs to be aware of which one it needs.
Change the cstor signature to this:

```
public RemoteDevice(IOptionsSnapshot<RemoteDeviceConfig> config, string section, ILogger<RemoteDevice> logger)
```

or

```
public RemoteDevice(IOptionsMonitor<RemoteDeviceConfig> config, string section, ILogger<RemoteDevice> logger)
```

IOptionsSnapshot and IOptionsMonitor allow us to get named configurations via the Get(string) method, and in the case of IOptionsMonitor, we can also observe and react to real-time changes in the configuration, provided that reloadOnChange was set to true when adding the json:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((IConfigurationBuilder builder) =>
{
    builder.AddJsonFile(path: configFile, optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
})
```

Finally, for each section that we have, we will add a new HostedService, and pass the name of the configuration to the cstor via the factory overload.

```
//continued...
services.AddHostedService<RemoteDevice>((IServiceProvider serv) =>
{
    return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<RemoteDevice>(serv, section.Path);
});
```

This way each configuration is, and can take full advantage of the framework around IHostedService

Comment: I tried to follow this advice but found that only the first instance of the HostedService got registered. The docs for the [`services.AddHostedService<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionhostedserviceextensions.addhostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0) say that "You shouldn't call this method multiple times for the same class. Doing so will only register the first HostedService you provide. To add multiple HostedServices, use AddSingleton<TService>(IServiceCollection) for each implementation of IHostedService explicitly."

Comment: Following the documentation recommendation to switch to `AddSingleton<IHostedService>()` rather than `AddHostedService<MyType>()` seems to work the way I expect.

Answer (score 0):

As I have faced similar problem recently - I am bumping this old question.

Consider using any mature DI container instead of default of default one.
Say with [Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59645123/using-autofac-with-asp-net-core-3-1-generic-host-worker-service-application) it will look like:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder => { builder.RegisterType<DeviceMainClass>(); })
            .ConfigureServices(services => { services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); })
            //...
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
}

public class DeviceConfig {
    //...
}

public class DeviceMainClass {
    private readonly ILogger<DeviceMainClass> _logger;
    private readonly DeviceConfig _deviceConfig;

    public DeviceMainClass(ILogger<DeviceMainClass> logger, DeviceConfig deviceConfig) {
        _logger = logger;
        _deviceConfig = deviceConfig;
    }
}

public class Worker : BackgroundService {
    List<DeviceMainClass> devices;

    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly List<DeviceConfig> _config;

    public Worker(IOptions<List<DeviceConfig>> options, Func<DeviceConfig, DeviceMainClass> deviceFactory, ILogger<Worker> logger) {
        _logger = logger;
        _config = options.Value;
        devices = new List<DeviceMainClass>();
        foreach (var deviceConfig in _config) {
            //autofac automatically adds appropriate logger when calling DeviceMainClass constructor                
            devices.Add(deviceFactory(deviceConfig)); 
        }

    }
}
```

Check for more details [here](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html) and [here](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html).